# Converting dates to a more readable format

Tags: javascript

Given an array of DateTime values that have been randomly selected between now and the next 7 days, how do I display relative time values, like:

- In 2 h
- In 3 d
- In 1 m

At the moment, [my program generates a random dateArray](http://jsbin.com/meripexuru/2/edit) with items in the following format, which I would ideally like to pass into a function that will return them into relative time format.

```
var timelineItemCount = getRandomInt(0, 19);
var dateArray = new Array();

    for(i=0;i<timelineItemCount;i++)
    {
        var today = new Date();
        var randomDates = randomDate(today, new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate()+7));
        dateArray.push(randomDates);
    }   
    dateArray.sort(function compare(a, B)/> {
        return (a < B)/> - (a > B)/>;
    });
    console.log(dateArray);

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function randomDate(start, end) {
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}
```

I have done some research, and so far seen examples on how to calculate relative time with values from the past, but I have not seen so much with values selected between now and the next 7 days. For example:

```
const int SECOND = 1;
const int MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;
const int HOUR = 60 * MINUTE;
const int DAY = 24 * HOUR;
const int MONTH = 30 * DAY;

var ts = new TimeSpan(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - yourDate.Ticks);
double delta = Math.Abs(ts.TotalSeconds);

if (delta < 0)
{
  return "not yet";
}
if (delta < 1 * MINUTE)
{
  return ts.Seconds == 1 ? "one second ago" : ts.Seconds + " seconds ago";
}
if (delta < 2 * MINUTE)
{
  return "a minute ago";
}
if (delta < 45 * MINUTE)
{
  return ts.Minutes + " minutes ago";
}
if (delta < 90 * MINUTE)
{
  return "an hour ago";
}
if (delta < 24 * HOUR)
{
  return ts.Hours + " hours ago";
}
if (delta < 48 * HOUR)
{
  return "yesterday";
}
if (delta < 30 * DAY)
{
  return ts.Days + " days ago";
}
if (delta < 12 * MONTH)
{
  int months = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)ts.Days / 30));
  return months <= 1 ? "one month ago" : months + " months ago";
}
else
{
  int years = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)ts.Days / 365));
  return years <= 1 ? "one year ago" : years + " years ago";
}
```

Comment: http://timeago.yarp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either write you own lib to do it or use an existing one:

- moment.js: http://momentjs.com/
- timeago: http://timeago.yarp.com/